# stack is popped in function still still shows in main function.Isn't the call should be by reference for the vector given

Tags: c++

stack is popped in function still still shows in main function.

Isn't the call should be by reference for the stack given.

```
    void showstack(stack <int> s)  { 
        while (!s.empty()) { 
            cout << '\t' << s.top(); 
            //stack getting popped
            s.pop(); 
        } 
    } 

    int main () { 
        stack <int> s; 
        s.push(10); 
        s.push(30); 
        s.push(5); 
        s.push(1); 
        cout << "The stack is : "; 
        showstack(s); 
        //The stack should be empty here.
        cout << "\ns.size() : " << s.size();//size should not get displayed 
        //top should be empty
        cout << "\ns.top() : " << s.top(); 
        cout << "\ns.pop() : "; 
        s.pop(); 
        showstack(s); 
        return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `showstack` modifies a copy of the stack `s`, and not the original stack. To work with the original stack pass it around by reference. `void showstack(stack <int>& s)`, note the `&`. Please be sure not to call `top()` on an empty stack after returning to main.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the call should be by reference for the stack given.

Yes it should, but you didn't.

> ```
>        //The stack should be empty here.
> ```

No, as you passed stack by value to `void showstack(stack <int> s)`, you manipulated a copy of it. The original instance of `s` stays unchanged.

If you want to operate that function on the original, change the signature to

```
void showstack(stack <int>& s)
                       // ^
```

to pass the stack by reference.

> ```
>        //size should not get displayed
> ```

Stack size can be always displayed.

> ```
>        //top should be empty
> ```

No, as for the same reasons as mentioned above.

Also note there's no *empty representation* for `top()`. Accessing it for an empty `std::stack` is simply *undefined behavior*.

Comment: so basically they are different form the arrays.. which are generally passed by reference.

Comment: @MohdZaid I don't see how _arrays_ are  related here at all. _"which are generally passed by reference."_ They aren't- Raw arrays [decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), that's it.